# How to display the field date (type of data date) in the last 3 months

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```
select date 
from datetime 
where tgl_valuta > TO_DATE('01/01/2019', 'dd-mm-yyyy');
```

I want to query for the display date in the last three months.

Comment: can you also post some code sample you have tried with regards to this. For example, a query you tried but did not work etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ADD_MONTHS`

```
select * from datetime where tgl_valuta > add_months(sysdate, -3)
```

This checks for exactly 3 months behind the current date (`sysdate`). If you want to compare from first day  of the 3rd previous month, you may add `TRUNC` with `MM` option

```
> TRUNC(add_months(sysdate, -3),'MM')
```

Comment: I understand `ADD_MONTHS` and `TRUNC`, but - what is `SYSDATE + 3` used for?

Comment: @Littlefoot : That's a mistake while doing a copy paste, thanks for pointing.

Comment: OK, no problem :)